# Undefined method route_name in Rspec controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When running my controller test, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `api_challenge_url' for #<Api::V1::ChallengesController:0x007f829b233460>
```

Which, is in fact, not a route that exists. My routes file looks like this:

```
namespace :api, { format: :json, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/'}  do
scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
  resources :users, only: [:show, :create, :update, :destroy] do
    resources :challenges, only: [:create, :show]
  end
 end
end
```

And my controller test looks like this:

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::ChallengesController, type: :controller do

describe "POST #create" do
 context "when successfully created" do

  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @challenge_attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:challenge)
    post :create, user_id: @user.id, challenge: @challenge_attributes, format: :json
  end

  it "should render the JSON for the created challenge" do
    challenge_response = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
    expect challenge_response[:description].to eql @challenge_attributes["description"]
    expect challenge_response[:title].to eql @challenge_attributes["title"]
  end
 end
end

end
```

But for the life of me, I can't why it's calling the wrong route name. The output of the relevant part of the `rake routes` looks like this:

```
api_user_challenges POST   /users/:user_id/challenges(.:format)     api/v1/challenges#create {:subdomain=>"api"}
```

I've tried a few different formats in the `post` method, is there some idiomatic way of doing this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some configuration to include url helpers into your test suite:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  # Other configurations ...
end
```

And if you prefer using `xxx_url` over `xxx_path`, remember to config `action_controller.default_url_options` in your `config/environments/test.rb`, for example:

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = {
  host: 'www.mysite.org',
  protocol: 'https'
}
```

Comment: I included it and there wasn't any change. I'm really confused as to why it's trying to use api_challenge_url, it seems like it's not scoping properly, but I feel like I'm following the proper pattern.